# Grep: Extract data from one file to update another

Tags: perl, sed, grep, extract

I'm writing a perl script which extracts values from one file with message definitions and uses them to update a config file.

For example:

Message Definition File (ICD.txt):

```
MESSAGE: FOO_TELEM
latitude [-90,90]
longitude [-180,180]
MESSAGE: FOO_FREQUENCY
airPressure [0,50]
engineSpeed [0,65500]
```

Where the FOO_TELEM message has members latitude with range -90 to 90 and longitude with range -180 to 180.

Config file (Config.txt):

```
  MessageTable
    Message FOO_TELEM
      Member latitude  DOUBLE End-Member
      Member longitude DOUBLE End-Member
    End-Message
    Message FOO_FREQUENCY
      Member airPressure ULONG End-Member
      Member engineSpeed ULONG End-Member
    End-Message
  End-MessageTable
```

I'd like to be able to update the config file (Config.txt) with the constraint values contained in the message definition file (ICD.txt), so that the result would look like this:

Updated Config file (Config.txt):

```
  MessageTable
    Message FOO_TELEM
      Member latitude  DOUBLE CONSTRAINT -90 90 End-Member
      Member longitude DOUBLE CONSTRAINT -180 180 End-Member
    End-Message
    Message FOO_FREQUENCY
      Member airPressure ULONG CONSTRAINT 0 50 End-Member
      Member engineSpeed ULONG CONSTRAINT 0 65500 End-Member
    End-Message
  End-MessageTable
```

I've tried various forms of grep to get the results I need but have been unsuccessful. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I'm open to any solutions involving grep, sed and/or perl.

Comment: would regular expressions work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a shot at it. I'm going to double-use `DATA` for my files, because I shouldn't have to write the open/close logic.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %messages;
my $current;
CONSTRAINT:
while ( <DATA> ) { 
    last CONSTRAINT if m/^---$/;
    if ( my ( $message ) = m/^ MESSAGE: \s+ ( \S+ )/x ) { 
        $messages{ $message } = $current = {};
    }
    elsif ( my ( $name, $min, $max ) 
               = m/^ (\w+) \s+ \[ \s* (-?\d+), \s* (-?\d+) \s* \]/x 
          ) { 
      $current->{ $name } = [ $min, $max ];
    }   
}
while ( <DATA> ) { 
    chomp;
    if ( my ( $msg ) = m/Message \s+ ( \S+ )/x ) { 
        $current = $messages{ $msg };
    }
    elsif (   ref( $current )
          and my ( $before, $member, $after ) 
                  = m/^( \s* Member \s+ ( \w+ ) \s+ \w+ ) \s+ (.*) /x 
          ) {
        if ( my $vals = $current->{ $member } ) { 
            $_ = "$before CONSTRAINT @$vals $after";
        }
    }
    say;
}

__DATA__
MESSAGE: FOO_TELEM
latitude [-90,90]
longitude [-180,180]
MESSAGE: FOO_FREQUENCY
airPressure [0,50]
engineSpeed [0,65500]
---
MessageTable
  Message FOO_TELEM
    Member latitude  DOUBLE End-Member
    Member longitude DOUBLE End-Member
  End-Message
  Message FOO_FREQUENCY
    Member airPressure ULONG End-Member
    Member engineSpeed ULONG End-Member
  End-Message
End-MessageTable
```

Answer (score 1):

First, write a parser to load the data into the following data structure:

```
my %data = (
   FOO_TELEM => {
      latitude  => [  -90,  90 ],
      longitude => [ -180, 180 ],
   },
   FOO_FREQUENCY => {
      latitude  => [ 0,    50 ],
      longitude => [ 0, 65500 ],
   },
);
```

Then, write a parser for your data definition format. The only addition is to have it look up `$data{$message_name}{$member_name}` when it finds an `End-Member`.

Answer (score 0):

Are any of these in some standard format? That would be helpful. For example, if your `Config.txt` file was in XML format, it would look something like this:

```
<messageTable>
    <message name="FOO_TELEM">
        <member name="latitude" type="DOUBLE"/>
        <member name="longitude" type="DOUBLE"/>
    </message>
    <message name="FOO_FREQUENCY">
        <member name="airPressure" type="ULONG"/>
        <member name="engineSpeed" type="ULONG"/>
    </message>
</messageTable>
```

If your files aren't in any specific standard format, can you get them into a standard format? It doesn't have to be XML, YAML is fine too.

The reason I'm asking is that Perl has oodles of modules for quickly parsing these standard formats in ways that makes everything so easy to manipulate. If not, you're going to have to manually parse your data to extract the information.

The easiest thing to do is parse your table and create a complex data structure in Perl to store your `ICD.txt` file's information. Perl has three standard data types, Scalars (variables like `$foo`), arrays (variables like `@foo`), and hashes (variables like `%hash`). Each of these data types deal with individual values. Scalars can contain only one individual value while arrays and hashes deal with lists of these values.

To deal with more complex structures, you need to use [Perl References](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html). References allow you to have a hash of hashes or an array of arrays, or a hash of arrays, or an array of hashes, etc.

For example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);
use autodie;
use Data::Dumper;

open my $icd_fh, "<", "icd.txt";

my %icd_data;
my $message;
while (my $line = <$icd_fh>) {
    if ($line =~ /^MESSAGE: (.*)/) {
        $message = $1;
    }
    else {
        $line =~ /(.*) \[(.*),(.*)\]/;
        my $message_type = $1;
        my $lower_limit = $2;
        my $upper_limit = $3;
        if (not exists $icd_data{$message}) {
            $icd_data{$message} = {};
        }
        $icd_data{$message}->{$message_type} = {};
        $icd_data{$message}->{$message_type}->{LOWER} = $lower_limit;
        $icd_data{$message}->{$message_type}->{UPPER} = $upper_limit;
    }
}
say Dumper \%icd_data;
```

This will get your ICD data in this shape:

```
$VAR1 = {
            'FOO_TELEM' => {
                'longitude' => {
                    'LOWER' => '-180',
                    'UPPER' => '180'
                 },
                 'latitude' => {
                      'LOWER' => '-90',
                      'UPPER' => '90'
                 }
            },
            'FOO_FREQUENCY' => {
                'airPressure' => {
                    'LOWER' => '0',
                    'UPPER' => '50'
                },
                'engineSpeed' => {
                    'LOWER' => '0',
                    'UPPER' => '65500'
                }
          }
    };
```

From there, you should be able to parse the lines of your `Config.txt` file, and modify them with the data you need.